# Unauthorized: Access Web API Dynamics 365 online from PHP

Tags: php, curl, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to call the Dynamics CRM 365 online using PHP, but I keep getting the same error:

> Error: failed with status 401, response HTTP Error 401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied , curl_error

This is my code

```
define('MS_CRM_URL', 'https://xxxx.crm4.dynamics.com');
define('MS_CRM_USER', 'xxxxx@xxxxx.onmicrosoft.com');
define('MS_CRM_PASS', 'xxxxxxxx');
$method = '/api/data/v8.2/contacts';

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, MS_CRM_URL . $method);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, MS_CRM_USER .':'. MS_CRM_PASS);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(

));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);    
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept' => 'application/json',
    'OData-MaxVersion' => '4.0',
    'OData-Version' => '4.0',
    'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
));

$server_output = curl_exec($ch);
$status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

curl_close($ch);

$json = array();
if ((int)$status_code === 200) {
    $json = json_decode($server_output);
}
```

Comment: Are you sure your credentials are correct/valid?

Comment: 100% sure. DO I have to have special persmissions on the CRM???

Comment: The only way to get that working is to use ADAL library, so I guess that you will have to use something like that in PHP (google says there are some ports of ADAL for PHP). Of course there are many steps to do before you will be able to authenticate against WebAPI, for example here: http://phuocle.net/crm/dynamics-365-online-s2s-authentication-full-explain.aspx